# ¿Cuál es la diferencia al escribir los arreglos vacíos dentro del método, en lugar de escribirlas como parámetros de objeto?

Tags: javascript, array, estructuras-de-datos

¿Cuál es la diferencia al escribir los arreglos vacíos dentro del método,

```
let = object {
...
calcMethod: function() {
        this.array1 = [];
        this.array2 = [];
    }
}
```

en lugar de escribirlas como parámetros de objeto?

```
let = object {
    ...
    array1 = [];
    array2 = [];

}
```

Para eventualmente llenarlos con datos.

Comment: traduce tu pregunta, estas en la versión en español de SO o de lo contrario terminará cerrada

Comment: Lo siento mucho, pensé que estaba en la versión en inglés. Normalmente manejo este tipo de información en inglés siempre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En este caso, es más bien una diferencia de cómo se va a hacer el llenado de las variables dentro del objeto.

#### Método 1

El método 1, supone un llenado de las variables a través de la función que los inicializa. Además, si la función no se ha llamado, los arreglos está indefinidos:

```js
let object ={
        calcMethod: function() {
            this.array1 = [];
            this.array2 = [];
        }
    }
    
    console.log(object.array1); // "undefined"
    console.log(object.array2); // "undefined"
    object.calcMethod();
    console.log(object.array1); // "[]"
    console.log(object.array2); // "[]"
```

#### Método 2

En el método 2, los objetos ya han sido instanciados e inicializados en el objeto, por lo que pueden ser referenciados sin ejecutar ninguna función:

```js
let object ={
  array1 : [],
  array2 : []
}
    console.log(object.array1); // "[]"
    console.log(object.array2); // "[]"
```

A mi parecer, es más un tema de estándar de inicialización, ya que en cuestiones de manejo de memoria, da lo mismo inicializarlos de una u otra forma.

Comment: Quedó bastante claro, muchas gracias!